# How to unmount flash drive gparted says busy

Tags: usb-drive, unmounting

I have a 4GB usb storage drive that I cannot save files to. I have copied the information I want from it, so now I would like to rescue is as a freshly formatted drive, if that is possible. There is no read-only lock switch on this device.

This is what happens:

```
[root@localhost]/home/Harry# cd /run/media/Harry/2030-0761
[root@localhost]/run/media/Harry/2030-0761# ls -l
ls: cannot access iambic11: Input/output error
total 40
drwx------ 35 Harry Harry 8192 Sep 16 16:46 arduinos
drwx------  5 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 16  2013 cranksmall
drwx------  2 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 18 13:08 iambic10
d?????????  ? ?     ?        ?            ? iambic11
drwx------  4 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 15  2013 Phasor1
drwx------  5 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 15  2013 Phasor2
drwx------  3 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 16 16:44 readfromarduino04
drwx------  3 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 19 18:18 readfromarduino07
drwx------  5 Harry Harry 4096 Aug  1  2013 SWR
drwx------  5 Harry Harry 4096 Sep 15  2013 SwrWinExe
[root@localhost]/run/media/Harry/2030-0761# rm iambic11
rm: cannot remove ‘iambic11’: Read-only file system
[root@localhost]/run/media/Harry/2030-0761# chmod 777 iambic11
chmod: cannot access ‘iambic11’: Input/output error
[root@localhost]/run/media/Harry/2030-0761#
```

`gparted` shows this drive but says it cannot be unmounted, and still shows the same even after:

```
[Harry@localhost]~% fuser -k /run/media/Harry/2030-0761
[Harry@localhost]~%
```

I am floundering in areas that are seldom visited by me, please can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo umount -v /run/media/Harry/2030-0761`.  If it says "device busy", try `lsof /run/media/Harry/2030-0761`; this will show applications that have something in the filesystem open.  It will likely be shells and file browsers.  Check those and navigate out of the filesystem and try `umount` again.

If that doesn't work, since you've said you intended to reformat this anyway, just pull it out, **disable automounting**, put it back in again and do what you want.